# Java currentTimeMillis() conversion to seconds not working?

Tags: java, time, milliseconds, seconds

Im trying to convert milliseconds to seconds with System.currentTimeMillis();

```
System.out.println((int) System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

The output is 730750 and increasing by 1. How can i get seconds starting from 0?

**UPDATE: Now i understand the problem and thank you for answering it.

Comment: Define "from 0"; what does zero mean in this case? Are you trying to determine an elasped time, for example?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but casting to `int` is definitely a problem. You are truncating that long before dividing which gives you a number that is incorrect for any question you might ask. Besides, `System.out.println()` is overloaded for all primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is from January 1, 1970. It will take today's time and subtract it from midnight January 1, 1970.  That is why it is so many seconds.

Answer (score 4):

From the Javadocs of [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()):

> Returns:
>   the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

To start from zero, you need to define a start time. Then you can print the time elapsed after that start time.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the time is based on the epoch 1.1.1970, you need to base it to the current time.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000l);
```

Comment: Okay i get it now, however my program stops counting at 4-5... Is it from lag?

Answer (score 3):

If you want elapsed time, you can store the start time and then later check the current time.
Ex.

```
int startTimeSeconds = (int) System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
// do stuff
System.out.println("Time elapsed: ");
System.out.println(((int) System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - startTimeSeconds);
```